# How is $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt {2-x}-\sqrt {2}}{x} = \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How is
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt {2-x}-\sqrt {2}}{x} = \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$ 
computable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying$$\frac{\sqrt{2-x}-\sqrt 2}{x}$$
by$$\frac{\sqrt{2-x}+\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{2-x}+\sqrt 2}$$
gives us
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2-x}-\sqrt 2}{x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sqrt{2-x}-\sqrt 2)(\sqrt{2-x}+\sqrt 2)}{x(\sqrt{2-x}+\sqrt 2)}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(2-x)-2}{x(\sqrt{2-x}+\sqrt 2)}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2-x}+\sqrt 2}\\&=\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2}\\&=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}.\end{align}$$

Comment: I did an I got -1 / $ \sqrt {2} + \sqrt {2} \ $

Comment: @Cetshwayo: I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: Can you explain the second to last part?

Comment: @Cetshwayo: You mean $\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2}=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt 2}$ ? This is because $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2=2\sqrt 2$.

Comment: okay, you just add them. I got it.

Comment: @Cetshwayo: Yes, I added them.

Answer (score 0):

You've already your answer, and here now is another approach. Put

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2-x}\;\implies f'(0):=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{2-x}-\sqrt2}x$$

and now just do the differentiation:

$$(\sqrt{2-x})'=-\frac1{2\sqrt{2-x}}\implies \left.(2-x)'\right|_{x=0}=-\frac1{2\sqrt2}$$